# Make nested loops as fast as possible

Tags: python-3.x

```
spatial_data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], ..... , [1,2,3,4,50,60]] #length 10 million
reference = [[9, 39, 22, 28, 25, 5], ...... , [5, 16, 12, 34, 3, 9]] # length 100

for x in reference:
    result = [c for c in spatial_data if len(set(x).intersection(c)) <= 2]
```

Each run will take my computer about 5 minutes, and I will need to perform this operation a projected 1000 times, and therefore I anticipate it will take about 3.5 days.  Please help me speed this up.  Thank you

I've tried writing this in a non-list comprehension format, which yield the same result of around 5 minutes per run.

Comment: Use NumPy instead?

Comment: 3.5 days, unless you run it in parallel. A 16 core machine will speed it up considerably already, although the algorithm / code can first be improved. Find five of such machines, and you're done within a lunch break.

Comment: What's the range of the numbers in the list? What does change between runs: `spacial_data`, `reference` or both? (I'm thinking about using bitsets)

Comment: could someone please show me how to code this in parallel?

Comment: Just run n amount of Python scripts in parallel, each with different inputs. Let the OS handle the parallellization. Try first with a few scripts, before using all cores.

Comment: `set(x)` is performed 1 billion times.

Answer (score 1):

Without any significant changes, you can shave a *lot* of work off this code. As written, you're creating one *billion* `set`s, then performing an intersection with them to create one billion *more* `set`s, because each test in your listcomp is recreating `set(x)` when it's going to be the same `set` 10M times in a row.

The fix is pretty trivial: Since you don't need the non-`set` version of `x`, convert it to a `set` as you iterate, halving the total work:

```
for x in map(set, reference):  # Convert to set once per reference element, not 10M times
    result = [c for c in spatial_data if len(x.intersection(c)) <= 2]  # Remove manual conversion to set
```

This won't be enough on its own (it might halve, or even slightly better than halve, the runtime, due to creating a smaller number of smaller `set`s), but you should definitely integrate it into any other solution that is still based on your initial design.

Answer (score 0):

A simple parallel version of your code using `multiprocessing.Pool` would be:

```
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

spatial_data = [...] #length 10 million
reference = [...] # length 100

def f(x, data):
    return [c for c in data if len(set(x).intersection(c)) <= 2]

my_func = partial(f, data=spatial_data) #since spatial_data is the same at each iteration

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    result = p.map(my_func, reference)
```

In short, you define a small function to do the inner loop calculation.
Then you spawn as many processes as you can (`cpu_count()` gives you the number of cores your hardware has) in a [Pool()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) using the [Pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) function.

That's the gist of it.

If it's for a one-time calculation, that's good enough. But a faster (and better) way would be using [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html). [See this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) for example.

Comment: unfortunately, I tried this and its still running after 10 minutes with no end in sight.  Not saying your example is wrongs this could possibly be something to do with M1 Mac processor

Comment: That's odd. Are you running it in a notebook, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Another version, using `numba` parallel JIT:

```py
from random import randint
from time import perf_counter
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

start = perf_counter()
spatial_data = [[randint(1, 60) for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(10_000_000)]
reference = [[randint(1, 60) for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(100)]
print("Data generated in", perf_counter() - start, "seconds")


@njit(parallel=True)
def _compute(spatial_data, reference):
    # precompute unique:
    spatial_data_uniq = [set(x) for x in spatial_data]
    reference_uniq = [set(x) for x in reference]

    out = [np.array([0], dtype=np.int32) for _ in range(len(reference))]
    for x in prange(len(reference_uniq)):
        out[x] = np.array(
            [
                i
                for i, c in enumerate(spatial_data_uniq)
                if len(reference_uniq[x].intersection(c)) <= 2
            ],
            dtype=np.int32,
        )
    return out


def compute(spatial_data, reference):
    out = _compute(
        np.array(spatial_data, dtype=np.int32), np.array(reference, dtype=np.int32)
    )
    return [[spatial_data[idx] for idx in indices] for indices in out]


# compile function
start = perf_counter()
compute([[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3]])
print("Function compiled in", perf_counter() - start, "seconds")

t1 = timeit("compute(spatial_data, reference)", number=1, globals=globals())
print("Function ran in", t1, "seconds")
```

This on my computer (AMD 5700x) has this result:

```
Data generated in 18.465883909957483 seconds
Function compiled in 2.1456540701910853 seconds
Function ran in 80.91065984289162 seconds

real    1m43,999s
user    0m0,010s
sys     0m0,007s
```